# Fql page liked returns empty array

Tags: facebook-fql

Im using this query and for some users it returns correct response but for some it returns empty array. I am only changing `userId`. Is it because of some privacy settings ?

`SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = pageId and uid = userId`

For some users it returns a good response:
`{
  "data": [
    {
      "uid": userId
    }
  ]
}`

and for some it returns a bad response like this even if they liked the page:
`{
  "data": [
  ]
}`

Im using extended permissions `read_stream`

Answer (score 0):

I updated my permissions with `user_likes` and uninstalled application and it works just fine.